# How to take that single line of input and separate it into the name, phone number, and city, and then create the dictionary key-value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struggling with this question:

> Create an entry from a single line obtained from `input()`, using a colon as the delimiter character (':') between the items.

> The prompt for input will be `'name:number:city'`. When you enter the values, you will literally type `"John:5739999999:Columbia"` or something similar with a ':' between the name, number, and city.

> You will need to take that single line of input and separate it into the name, phone number, and city, and then create the dictionary key-value pairs like you did in the previous question.

Example Output:

```
name:number:city John:5739999999:Columbia
{'city': 'Columbia', 'name': 'John', 'number': '5739999999'}
```

Here is my code:

```
entry = {}
# Your code between these lines
# ----------------------------

entry[input("Name:Number:City ")] = ("Name:Number:City").split(':')

print(entry)
# ----------------------------
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the smallest solution

When you `split()` a line, it splits the string into a list based on the condition. `zip()` links all the elements with the specific index.

```
line="name:number:city"
x=input(line)
print(dict(zip(line.split(":"),x.split(":"))))
```

Output:

```
name:number:cityJohn:5739999999:Columbia
{'name': 'John', 'number': '5739999999', 'city': 'Columbia'}
```

Comment: Most welcome @AnthonyLoya, consider upvoting and accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Not the smallest solution but, A step by step solution for beginner for the better understanding.

```
user_input = input("Name:Number:City") 

# example-input : John:5739999999:Columbia

values = user_input.split(":")

# values = [John, 5739999999, Columbia]

entry = {}
entry["city"]=values[2]
entry["name"]=values[0]
entry["number"]=values[1]

# output : {'city': 'Columbia', 'name': 'John', 'number': '5739999999'}
```